# How to convert array of array (string type) to struct - Spark/Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.3

I have a dataframe as

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|family_name                                                    |id |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[[John, Doe, Married, 999-999-9999],[Jane, Doe, Married,Wife,]]|id1|
|[[Tom, Riddle, Single, 888-888-8888]]                          |id2|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
root
 |-- family_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I wish to convert the column `fam_name` to array of named structs as

```
`family_name` array<struct<f_name:string,l_name:string,status:string,ph_no:string>>
```

Im able to convert `family_name` to array as shown below

```
val sch = ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType))

val fam_array = data
        .withColumn("family_name_clean", regexp_replace($"family_name", "\\[\\[", "["))
        .withColumn("family_name_clean_clean1", regexp_replace($"family_name_clean", "\\]\\]", "]"))
        .withColumn("ar", toArray($"family_name_clean_clean1"))
        //.withColumn("ar1", from_json($"ar", sch))
    fam_array.show(false)
    fam_array.printSchema()

+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|family_name                                                    |id |family_name_clean                                             |family_name_clean_clean1                                     |ar                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[John, Doe, Married, 999-999-9999],[Jane, Doe, Married,Wife,]]|id1|[John, Doe, Married, 999-999-9999],[Jane, Doe, Married,Wife,]]|[John, Doe, Married, 999-999-9999],[Jane, Doe, Married,Wife,]|[[John,  Doe,  Married,  999-999-9999], [Jane,  Doe,  Married, Wife, ]]|
|[[Tom, Riddle, Single, 888-888-8888]]                          |id2|[Tom, Riddle, Single, 888-888-8888]]                          |[Tom, Riddle, Single, 888-888-8888]                          |[[Tom,  Riddle,  Single,  888-888-8888]]                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
root
 |-- family_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- family_name_clean: string (nullable = true)
 |-- family_name_clean_clean1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ar: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

`sch` is a schema variable of desired type.

How do I convert column `ar` to `array<struct<>>` ?

**EDIT:**

I'm using Spark 2.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To create an array of structs given an array of arrays of strings, you can use [`struct` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#struct(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to build a struct given a list of columns combined with [`element_at` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#element_at(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to extract column element at a specific index of an array.**

To solve your specific problem, as you correctly stated you need to do two things:

- First, transform your string to an array of arrays of strings
- Then, use this array of arrays of strings to build your struct

#### In Spark 3.0 and greater

Using Spark 3.0, we can perform all those steps using spark built-in functions.

For the first step, I would do as follows:

- first remove `[[` and `]]` from `family_name` string using [`regexp_replace` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String,replacement:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
- then, create first array level by splitting this string using [`split` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#split(str:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:String,limit:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
- then, create second array level by splitting each element of previous array using [`transform`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and `split` functions

And for the second step, use [`struct` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#struct(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to build a `struct`, picking element in arrays using [`element_at` function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#element_at(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

Thus, complete code using Spark 3.0 and greater would be as follows, with `data` as input dataframe:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, element_at, regexp_replace, split, struct, transform}

val result = data
  .withColumn(
    "family_name", 
    transform( 
      split( // first level split
        regexp_replace(col("family_name"), "\\[\\[|]]", ""), // remove [[ and ]]
        "],\\["
      ), 
      x => split(x, ",") // split for each element in first level array
    )
  )
  .withColumn("family_name", transform(col("family_name"), x => struct(
    element_at(x, 1).as("f_name"), // index starts at 1
    element_at(x, 2).as("l_name"),
    element_at(x, 3).as("status"),
    element_at(x, -1).as("ph_no"), // get last element of array
  )))
```

#### In Spark 2.X

Using Spark 2.X, we have to rely on an user-defined function. First, we need to define a `case class` that represent our `struct`:

```scala
case class FamilyName(
  f_name: String, 
  l_name: String, 
  status: String, 
  ph_no: String
)
```

Then, we define our user-defined function and apply it to our input dataframe:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val extract_array = udf((familyName: String) => familyName
  .replaceAll("\\[\\[|]]", "")
  .split("],\\[")
  .map(familyName => {
    val explodedFamilyName = familyName.split(",", -1)
    FamilyName(
      f_name = explodedFamilyName(0),
      l_name = explodedFamilyName(1),
      status = explodedFamilyName(2),
      ph_no = explodedFamilyName(explodedFamilyName.length - 1)
    )
  })
)

val result = data.withColumn("family_name", extract_array(col("family_name")))
```

#### Result

If you have the following `data` dataframe:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|family_name                                                    |id |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[[John, Doe, Married, 999-999-9999],[Jane, Doe, Married,Wife,]]|id1|
|[[Tom, Riddle, Single, 888-888-8888]]                          |id2|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

You get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|family_name                                                      |id |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[{John,  Doe,  Married,  999-999-9999}, {Jane,  Doe,  Married, }]|id1|
|[{Tom,  Riddle,  Single,  888-888-8888}]                         |id2|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

having the following schema:

```
root
 |-- family_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- f_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- l_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ph_no: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank you for this elegant solution and explanation. It makes perfect sense to me,. Its jus that I'm, using Spark 2.3.2 (I will add this as an edit to my OP).

Comment: Can you please show how I can achieve the same in Spark 2.3.X ?

Comment: I added the solution for Spark 2.X